# sqlite select ' max ' values simultanously on 2 columns

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Here is my sqlite table :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST 
(ID             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   NOT NULL,
 DAY            DATE                  NOT NULL,
 HOUR           TIME                  NOT NULL,
 VALUE          REAL                  NOT NULL,
 COEF           REAL)
```

My values :

```
║   DAY         ║  HOUR    ║  VALUE     ║  COEF ║  
║  '2016-01-19' ║  '16:00' ║  '11240.0' ║  '0.5'║  
║  '2016-01-19' ║  '18:00' ║  '11244.0' ║  '0.2'║  
║  '2016-01-22' ║  '20:30' ║  '11254.0' ║  '0.6'║  
║  '2016-01-23' ║  '12:25' ║  '11256.0' ║  '0.8'║  
║  '2016-01-23' ║  '14:40' ║  '11257.0' ║  '0.3'║  
║  '2016-01-24' ║  '09:40' ║  '11259.0' ║  '0.4'║  
║  '2016-01-24' ║  '19:45' ║  '11260.0' ║  '0.5'║  
║  '2016-01-25' ║  '18:50' ║  '11263.0' ║  '0.6'║  
║  '2016-01-26' ║  '18:40' ║  '11266.0' ║  '0.1'║  
║  '2016-01-31' ║  '20:00' ║  '11278.0' ║  '0.9'║  
║  '2016-01-31' ║  '22:00' ║  '11280.0' ║  '0.3'║  
║  '2016-02-03' ║  '21:40' ║  '11285.0' ║  '0.4'║  
║  '2016-02-05' ║  '10:10' ║  '11290.0' ║  '0.2'║
```

I would like to select for each 'WeekNumber' the ' Max(DAY) ' value according to the latest ' HOUR ' of that ' Max(DAY) '.

So far, I have this request :

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', DAY, 'weekday 0') WeekNumber, MAX(DAY), HOUR, 
 MAX(VALUE), MAX(VALUE)-MIN(VALUE), COEF  
FROM TEST  
WHERE DAY >= '2016-01-19' AND DAY <= '2017-03-31'  
GROUP BY WeekNumber  
ORDER BY WeekNumber ASC
```

That query get that result :

```
║ "2016-01-24" ║ "2016-01-24" ║ "16:00" ║ "11260.0" ║ "20.0" ║ "0.5" ║ 
║ "2016-01-31" ║ "2016-01-31" ║ "18:50" ║ "11280.0" ║ "17.0" ║ "0.6" ║ 
║ "2016-02-07" ║ "2016-02-05" ║ "21:40" ║ "11290.0" ║  "5.0" ║ "0.4" ║
```

In this result, on line '2016-01-24' the ' HOUR ' column is to ' 16:00 ' value, but I need to obtain ' 19:45 '... I need to get the latest hour of that particular last week day.

(same thing on result line '2016-01-31', which should be ' HOUR = 22:00 ')

How could I proceed with the request to have that work ?

( I can't use in the request ' Max(HOUR) ' because it results the highest hour in the week, but no the one for the latest day of the week as I want to)

Thanks for any idea

Comment: Please add insert SQL to populate your test table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to make a helper table named MAXH of max hours each day.
Temporary tables that exists only for the duration of the query is created using WITH like this:

```
with
maxh as (select day, max(hour) max_hour from test group by day),
result as (
  select
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d', day, 'weekday 0') weeknumber,
    max(day)                               max_day,
    max(value)                             max_value,
    max(value)-min(value)                  diff,
                                           coef
  from test  
  where day between '2016-01-19' and '2017-03-31'
  group by weeknumber
)
select
  weeknumber,
  max_day,
  (select max_hour from maxh where day=max_day) max_hour_that_day,
  max_value,
  diff,
  coef
from result order by 1;
```

Result on your test table:

```
2016-01-24|2016-01-24|19:45|11260.0|20.0|0.5
2016-01-31|2016-01-31|22:00|11280.0|17.0|0.6
2016-02-07|2016-02-05|10:10|11290.0|5.0|0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, here are the ' insert ' :

INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-19','16:00','11240.0','0.5');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-19','18:00','11244.0','0.2');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-22','20:30','11254.0','0.6');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-23','12:25','11256.0','0.8');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-23','14:40','11257.0','0.3');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-24','09:40','11259.0','0.4');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-24','19:45','11260.0','0.5');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-25','18:50','11263.0','0.6');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-26','18:40','11266.0','0.1');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-31','20:00','11278.0','0.9');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-01-31','22:00','11280.0','0.3');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-02-03','21:40','11285.0','0.4');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DAY, HOUR, VALUE, COEF) VALUES (NULL,'2016-02-05','10:10','11290.0','0.2');

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply, it works indeed.

But in the meantime, I also find another solution :

> SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', TEST.DAY, 'weekday 0') WeekNumber, 
> MAX(TEST.DAY) AS MAXDAY, t1.MAXHOUR, MAX(TEST.VALUE), MAX(TEST.VALUE)-MIN(TEST.VALUE), TEST.COEF   
>   FROM TEST, ( SELECT DAY, MAX(HOUR) AS MAXHOUR FROM TEST GROUP BY DAY   ) AS t1 
>   GROUP BY WeekNumber, t1.DAY
>   HAVING t1.DAY = MAXDAY
>   AND TEST.DAY >= '2016-01-19' AND TEST.DAY <= '2017-03-31'

Thanks again for your help !